# How to have two svg clock on one page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

The first clock works fine, but if I duplicate another set of script for the second clock, the second clock cannot display properly. I already label the first clock of codes as (For desktop version) comment and another clock of codes label as (For mobile version) for you guys to differentiate the two set of codes.

```
<!--For desktop version-->      
    <div id="svgtimedesktop">   

        <svg
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   version="1.1"
   onload="startUp()">

<script>

<![CDATA[

/* Evolved from DHTML version 
   @ http://www.dhteumeuleu.com */

var xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var xlinkns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"; 

var backX0;
var backY0;
var backWidth;
var backHeight;

var O=[];
var TM=[];
var Tm=[];
var A = 1000;


var digits = [
" ###   #  #### #### #   ###### ### ##### ###  ###      ",
"#   #  #      #    ##   ##    #   #    ##   ##   #     ",
"#   #  #      #    ##   ##    #        ##   ##   #  #  ",
"#   #  #   ###  ### ######### ####     # ###  ####     ",
"#   #  #  #        #    #    ##   #    ##   #    #  #  ",
"#   #  #  #        #    #    ##   #    ##   ##   #     ",
" ###   #  #########     #####  ###     # ###  ###      "
];


function startUp() {

      var myBack = document.getElementById("backGround");
      backX0 = myBack.getAttributeNS(null,"x");
      backY0 = myBack.getAttributeNS(null,"y");
      backWidth = myBack.getAttributeNS(null,"width");
      backHeight = myBack.getAttributeNS(null,"height");

      dayDisplay();
    timer();

      /* 
         k        0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7   -> 1st args of Cdigit
        display   *  *  :  *  *  :  *  *   -> 2nd args of Cdigit 
                                              ('10' for ':')
      */
      var k=0;   
    for(var i=0;i<6;i++){
        O[k] = new Cdigit(k++, TM[i]);
        if(i==1 || i==3) O[k] = new Cdigit(k++, 10);
    }      
    mainloop();
}

/* Input for Cdigit
   N = 0-7
   d = 0-9 or 10 */

function Cdigit(N,d){
    // digit prototype: 5 x 7 dots for each of digit from 0 to 9
    this.O = [];
    for(var i=0;i<7;i++){
        for(var j=0;j<5;j++){
            if(digits[i].charAt(5*d+j)!=" "){
                this.O.push(
                              // COjb(this.a, this.z)
                    new CObj((
                        (28*N)+(j*5))/(180/Math.PI),
                        -42+i*12
                    )
                );
            }
        }
    }
}

function CObj(a,z){
    // create led element
    this.o = document.createElementNS(xmlns,"circle");
    document.getElementById("clock3D").appendChild(this.o);
    this.a=a;
    this.z=z;
    this.plot=true;
}

// leds lighting

// main 3D function
CObj.prototype.anim=function() {
        // z axis rotation
            var x=Math.sin(A+this.a)*100;
        var y=Math.cos(A+this.a)*100;
        // simple 3D
        var x1=y;
        var zz=this.z;
        var y1=-zz;
        zz=x;
        // 2D projection
        var r=396/(396+zz);
        x=Math.round(backWidth/2-x1/r)+parseFloat(backX0);
        y=Math.round(backHeight/2-y1/r)+parseFloat(backY0);

        // leds lighting
        if(zz>0){
                this.o.setAttributeNS(null,"fill","#ff0000");
                this.o.setAttributeNS(null,"cx",x);
                this.o.setAttributeNS(null,"cy",y);
                this.o.setAttributeNS(null,"r","5");
                this.o.setAttributeNS(null,"opacity","1.0");
        } 
        else {
                        this.o.setAttributeNS(null,"fill","#00ff00");
                this.o.setAttributeNS(null,"cx",x);
                this.o.setAttributeNS(null,"cy",y);
                this.o.setAttributeNS(null,"r","5");
                        this.o.setAttributeNS(null,"opacity","0.3");
        }   
    }

function mainloop() {
    // rotation speed
    A-=Math.PI/120; 
    // refresh time
    k=0;
    for(var i=0;i<6;i++){
        if(TM[i]!=Tm[i]){
            Tm[i]=TM[i];
            // destroy objects
            for(var j in O[k].O)document.getElementById("clock3D").removeChild(O[k].O[j].o);
            delete O[k];
            // create new digit
            O[k] = new Cdigit(k, TM[i]);
        }
            // skip colons
        k+=(i==1 || i==3)?2:1;
    }
    // call animation
    for(var i in O){
        for(var j in O[i].O){
            O[i].O[j].anim();
        }
    }
    setTimeout("mainloop()",20);
}

function timer(){
    // HH:MM:SS
    T = new Date();
    h = T.getHours();
    m = T.getMinutes();
    s = T.getSeconds();

    TM = [
        Math.floor(h/10),
        h%10,
        Math.floor(m/10),
        m%10,
        Math.floor(s/10),
        s%10
    ];
    setTimeout("timer()" ,1000); 
}

function dayDisplay()
{
    var dayName = 
         new Array("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Thursday",
                    "Friday","Saturday");
      var monthName = 
         new Array("January","February","March","April","May","June","July",
"August","September","October","November","December");

    var today = new Date();

    document.getElementById("date").firstChild.nodeValue = 
            dayName[today.getDay()-1]+", "
                + monthName[today.getMonth()]+" "
                + today.getDate()+", "+today.getFullYear();
}

]]>

</script>


<rect id="backGround" x="50" y="50" width="300" height="200" fill="black" stroke="#444" stroke-width="5"/>
<rect id="backGround" x="53" y="53" width="294" height="194" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="1"/>

<g id="clock3D">
 <circle id="red" cx="-150" cy="-150" r="4" fill="red"/>
 <circle id="green" cx="-150" cy="-150" r="4" fill="green" opacity="0.3"/>
</g>

<text id="date" x="80" y="240" font-size="20" fill="white">
date
    <animate attributeName="opacity" dur="5s" 
      values="1;0;1" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
</text>

</svg>

</div>









    <!--For mobile version-->   
            <div id="svgtimemobile"> 

            <svg
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   version="1.1"
   onload="startUp()">

<script>

<![CDATA[

/* Evolved from DHTML version 
   @ http://www.dhteumeuleu.com */

var xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var xlinkns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"; 

var backX0;
var backY0;
var backWidth;
var backHeight;

var O=[];
var TM=[];
var Tm=[];
var A = 1000;


var digits = [
" ###   #  #### #### #   ###### ### ##### ###  ###      ",
"#   #  #      #    ##   ##    #   #    ##   ##   #     ",
"#   #  #      #    ##   ##    #        ##   ##   #  #  ",
"#   #  #   ###  ### ######### ####     # ###  ####     ",
"#   #  #  #        #    #    ##   #    ##   #    #  #  ",
"#   #  #  #        #    #    ##   #    ##   ##   #     ",
" ###   #  #########     #####  ###     # ###  ###      "
];


function startUp() {

      var myBack = document.getElementById("backGround");
      backX0 = myBack.getAttributeNS(null,"x");
      backY0 = myBack.getAttributeNS(null,"y");
      backWidth = myBack.getAttributeNS(null,"width");
      backHeight = myBack.getAttributeNS(null,"height");

      dayDisplay();
    timer();

      /* 
         k        0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7   -> 1st args of Cdigit
        display   *  *  :  *  *  :  *  *   -> 2nd args of Cdigit 
                                              ('10' for ':')
      */
      var k=0;   
    for(var i=0;i<6;i++){
        O[k] = new Cdigit(k++, TM[i]);
        if(i==1 || i==3) O[k] = new Cdigit(k++, 10);
    }      
    mainloop();
}

/* Input for Cdigit
   N = 0-7
   d = 0-9 or 10 */

function Cdigit(N,d){
    // digit prototype: 5 x 7 dots for each of digit from 0 to 9
    this.O = [];
    for(var i=0;i<7;i++){
        for(var j=0;j<5;j++){
            if(digits[i].charAt(5*d+j)!=" "){
                this.O.push(
                              // COjb(this.a, this.z)
                    new CObj((
                        (28*N)+(j*5))/(180/Math.PI),
                        -42+i*12
                    )
                );
            }
        }
    }
}

function CObj(a,z){
    // create led element
    this.o = document.createElementNS(xmlns,"circle");
    document.getElementById("clock3D").appendChild(this.o);
    this.a=a;
    this.z=z;
    this.plot=true;
}

// leds lighting

// main 3D function
CObj.prototype.anim=function() {
        // z axis rotation
            var x=Math.sin(A+this.a)*100;
        var y=Math.cos(A+this.a)*100;
        // simple 3D
        var x1=y;
        var zz=this.z;
        var y1=-zz;
        zz=x;
        // 2D projection
        var r=396/(396+zz);
        x=Math.round(backWidth/2-x1/r)+parseFloat(backX0);
        y=Math.round(backHeight/2-y1/r)+parseFloat(backY0);

        // leds lighting
        if(zz>0){
                this.o.setAttributeNS(null,"fill","#ff0000");
                this.o.setAttributeNS(null,"cx",x);
                this.o.setAttributeNS(null,"cy",y);
                this.o.setAttributeNS(null,"r","5");
                this.o.setAttributeNS(null,"opacity","1.0");
        } 
        else {
                        this.o.setAttributeNS(null,"fill","#00ff00");
                this.o.setAttributeNS(null,"cx",x);
                this.o.setAttributeNS(null,"cy",y);
                this.o.setAttributeNS(null,"r","5");
                        this.o.setAttributeNS(null,"opacity","0.3");
        }   
    }

function mainloop() {
    // rotation speed
    A-=Math.PI/120; 
    // refresh time
    k=0;
    for(var i=0;i<6;i++){
        if(TM[i]!=Tm[i]){
            Tm[i]=TM[i];
            // destroy objects
            for(var j in O[k].O)document.getElementById("clock3D").removeChild(O[k].O[j].o);
            delete O[k];
            // create new digit
            O[k] = new Cdigit(k, TM[i]);
        }
            // skip colons
        k+=(i==1 || i==3)?2:1;
    }
    // call animation
    for(var i in O){
        for(var j in O[i].O){
            O[i].O[j].anim();
        }
    }
    setTimeout("mainloop()",20);
}

function timer(){
    // HH:MM:SS
    T = new Date();
    h = T.getHours();
    m = T.getMinutes();
    s = T.getSeconds();

    TM = [
        Math.floor(h/10),
        h%10,
        Math.floor(m/10),
        m%10,
        Math.floor(s/10),
        s%10
    ];
    setTimeout("timer()" ,1000); 
}

function dayDisplay()
{
    var dayName = 
         new Array("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Thursday",
                    "Friday","Saturday");
      var monthName = 
         new Array("January","February","March","April","May","June","July",
"August","September","October","November","December");

    var today = new Date();

    document.getElementById("date").firstChild.nodeValue = 
            dayName[today.getDay()-1]+", "
                + monthName[today.getMonth()]+" "
                + today.getDate()+", "+today.getFullYear();
}

]]>

</script>


<rect id="backGround" x="3" y="50" width="247" height="200" fill="black" stroke="#444" stroke-width="5"/>
<rect id="backGround" x="3" y="53" width="247" height="194" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="1"/>

<g id="clock3D">
 <circle id="red" cx="-150" cy="1000" r="4" fill="red"/>
 <circle id="green" cx="-150" cy="-150" r="4" fill="green" opacity="0.3"/>
</g>

<text id="date" x="5" y="240" font-size="20" fill="white">
date
    <animate attributeName="opacity" dur="5s" 
      values="1;0;1" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
</text>

</svg>

</div>
```

I put the number 2 behind every function and ids and whatever names that I think that needs to have a 2 behind for the mobile version codes and it still cannot display properly. I can't spot for any more that needs the number 2 behind already. If i copy the mobile version codes and paste in a new page without the desktop version codes, it worked fine. Only when the desktop version and mobile version codes is together, either one will not display properly. What else needs to be edited? Below is my edited codes for the mobile version.

```
<!--For desktop version-->      
    <div id="svgtimedesktop">   


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>

<svg
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   version="1.1"
   onload="startUp()">

<script>

<![CDATA[

/* Evolved from DHTML version 
   @ http://www.dhteumeuleu.com */

var xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var xlinkns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"; 

var backX0;
var backY0;
var backWidth;
var backHeight;

var O=[];
var TM=[];
var Tm=[];
var A = 1000;


var digits = [
" ###   #  #### #### #   ###### ### ##### ###  ###      ",
"#   #  #      #    ##   ##    #   #    ##   ##   #     ",
"#   #  #      #    ##   ##    #        ##   ##   #  #  ",
"#   #  #   ###  ### ######### ####     # ###  ####     ",
"#   #  #  #        #    #    ##   #    ##   #    #  #  ",
"#   #  #  #        #    #    ##   #    ##   ##   #     ",
" ###   #  #########     #####  ###     # ###  ###      "
];


function startUp() {

      var myBack = document.getElementById("backGround");
      backX0 = myBack.getAttributeNS(null,"x");
      backY0 = myBack.getAttributeNS(null,"y");
      backWidth = myBack.getAttributeNS(null,"width");
      backHeight = myBack.getAttributeNS(null,"height");

      dayDisplay();
    timer();

      /* 
         k        0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7   -> 1st args of Cdigit
        display   *  *  :  *  *  :  *  *   -> 2nd args of Cdigit 
                                              ('10' for ':')
      */
      var k=0;   
    for(var i=0;i<6;i++){
        O[k] = new Cdigit(k++, TM[i]);
        if(i==1 || i==3) O[k] = new Cdigit(k++, 10);
    }      
    mainloop();
}

/* Input for Cdigit
   N = 0-7
   d = 0-9 or 10 */

function Cdigit(N,d){
    // digit prototype: 5 x 7 dots for each of digit from 0 to 9
    this.O = [];
    for(var i=0;i<7;i++){
        for(var j=0;j<5;j++){
            if(digits[i].charAt(5*d+j)!=" "){
                this.O.push(
                              // COjb(this.a, this.z)
                    new CObj((
                        (28*N)+(j*5))/(180/Math.PI),
                        -42+i*12
                    )
                );
            }
        }
    }
}

function CObj(a,z){
    // create led element
    this.o = document.createElementNS(xmlns,"circle");
    document.getElementById("clock3D").appendChild(this.o);
    this.a=a;
    this.z=z;
    this.plot=true;
}

// leds lighting

// main 3D function
CObj.prototype.anim=function() {
        // z axis rotation
            var x=Math.sin(A+this.a)*100;
        var y=Math.cos(A+this.a)*100;
        // simple 3D
        var x1=y;
        var zz=this.z;
        var y1=-zz;
        zz=x;
        // 2D projection
        var r=396/(396+zz);
        x=Math.round(backWidth/2-x1/r)+parseFloat(backX0);
        y=Math.round(backHeight/2-y1/r)+parseFloat(backY0);

        // leds lighting
        if(zz>0){
                this.o.setAttributeNS(null,"fill","#ff0000");
                this.o.setAttributeNS(null,"cx",x);
                this.o.setAttributeNS(null,"cy",y);
                this.o.setAttributeNS(null,"r","5");
                this.o.setAttributeNS(null,"opacity","1.0");
        } 
        else {
                        this.o.setAttributeNS(null,"fill","#00ff00");
                this.o.setAttributeNS(null,"cx",x);
                this.o.setAttributeNS(null,"cy",y);
                this.o.setAttributeNS(null,"r","5");
                        this.o.setAttributeNS(null,"opacity","0.3");
        }   
    }

function mainloop() {
    // rotation speed
    A-=Math.PI/120; 
    // refresh time
    k=0;
    for(var i=0;i<6;i++){
        if(TM[i]!=Tm[i]){
            Tm[i]=TM[i];
            // destroy objects
            for(var j in O[k].O)document.getElementById("clock3D").removeChild(O[k].O[j].o);
            delete O[k];
            // create new digit
            O[k] = new Cdigit(k, TM[i]);
        }
            // skip colons
        k+=(i==1 || i==3)?2:1;
    }
    // call animation
    for(var i in O){
        for(var j in O[i].O){
            O[i].O[j].anim();
        }
    }
    setTimeout("mainloop()",20);
}

function timer(){
    // HH:MM:SS
    T = new Date();
    h = T.getHours();
    m = T.getMinutes();
    s = T.getSeconds();

    TM = [
        Math.floor(h/10),
        h%10,
        Math.floor(m/10),
        m%10,
        Math.floor(s/10),
        s%10
    ];
    setTimeout("timer()" ,1000); 
}

function dayDisplay()
{
    var dayName = 
         new Array("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Thursday",
                    "Friday","Saturday");
      var monthName = 
         new Array("January","February","March","April","May","June","July",
"August","September","October","November","December");

    var today = new Date();

    document.getElementById("date").firstChild.nodeValue = 
            dayName[today.getDay()-1]+", "
                + monthName[today.getMonth()]+" "
                + today.getDate()+", "+today.getFullYear();
}

]]>

</script>


<rect id="backGround" x="50" y="50" width="300" height="200" fill="black" stroke="#444" stroke-width="5"/>
<rect id="backGround" x="53" y="53" width="294" height="194" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="1"/>

<g id="clock3D">
 <circle id="red" cx="-150" cy="-150" r="4" fill="red"/>
 <circle id="green" cx="-150" cy="-150" r="4" fill="green" opacity="0.3"/>
</g>

<text id="date" x="80" y="240" font-size="20" fill="white">
date
    <animate attributeName="opacity" dur="5s" 
      values="1;0;1" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
</text>

</svg>

</div>








    <!--For mobile version-->   
            <div id="svgtimemobile"> 

            <svg
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   version="1.1"
   onload="startUp2()">

<script>

<![CDATA[

/* Evolved from DHTML version 
   @ http://www.dhteumeuleu.com */

var xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var xlinkns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"; 

var backX0;
var backY0;
var backWidth;
var backHeight;

var O=[];
var TM=[];
var Tm=[];
var A = 1000;


var digits = [
" ###   #  #### #### #   ###### ### ##### ###  ###      ",
"#   #  #      #    ##   ##    #   #    ##   ##   #     ",
"#   #  #      #    ##   ##    #        ##   ##   #  #  ",
"#   #  #   ###  ### ######### ####     # ###  ####     ",
"#   #  #  #        #    #    ##   #    ##   #    #  #  ",
"#   #  #  #        #    #    ##   #    ##   ##   #     ",
" ###   #  #########     #####  ###     # ###  ###      "
];

function startUp2() {

      var myBack2 = document.getElementById("backGround2");
      backX0 = myBack2.getAttributeNS(null,"x");
      backY0 = myBack2.getAttributeNS(null,"y");
      backWidth = myBack2.getAttributeNS(null,"width");
      backHeight = myBack2.getAttributeNS(null,"height");

      dayDisplay2();
    timer2();

      /* 
         k        0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7   -> 1st args of Cdigit
        display   *  *  :  *  *  :  *  *   -> 2nd args of Cdigit 
                                              ('10' for ':')
      */
      var k=0;   
    for(var i=0;i<6;i++){
        O[k] = new Cdigit2(k++, TM[i]);
        if(i==1 || i==3) O[k] = new Cdigit2(k++, 10);
    }      
    mainloop2();
}

/* Input for Cdigit
   N = 0-7
   d = 0-9 or 10 */

function Cdigit2(N2,d2){
    // digit prototype: 5 x 7 dots for each of digit from 0 to 9
    this.O = [];
    for(var i=0;i<7;i++){
        for(var j=0;j<5;j++){
            if(digits[i].charAt(5*d2+j)!=" "){
                this.O.push(
                              // COjb(this.a, this.z)
                    new CObj2((
                        (28*N2)+(j*5))/(180/Math.PI),
                        -42+i*12
                    )
                );
            }
        }
    }
}

function CObj2(a2,z2){
    // create led element
    this.o = document.createElementNS(xmlns,"circle");
    document.getElementById("clock3D2").appendChild(this.o);
    this.a=a2;
    this.z=z2;
    this.plot2=true;
}

// leds lighting

// main 3D function
CObj2.prototype.anim2=function() {
        // z axis rotation
            var x=Math.sin(A+this.a)*100;
        var y=Math.cos(A+this.a)*100;
        // simple 3D
        var x1=y;
        var zz=this.z;
        var y1=-zz;
        zz=x;
        // 2D projection
        var r=396/(396+zz);
        x=Math.round(backWidth/2-x1/r)+parseFloat(backX0);
        y=Math.round(backHeight/2-y1/r)+parseFloat(backY0);

        // leds lighting
        if(zz>0){
                this.o.setAttributeNS(null,"fill","#ff0000");
                this.o.setAttributeNS(null,"cx",x);
                this.o.setAttributeNS(null,"cy",y);
                this.o.setAttributeNS(null,"r","5");
                this.o.setAttributeNS(null,"opacity","1.0");
        } 
        else {
                        this.o.setAttributeNS(null,"fill","#00ff00");
                this.o.setAttributeNS(null,"cx",x);
                this.o.setAttributeNS(null,"cy",y);
                this.o.setAttributeNS(null,"r","5");
                        this.o.setAttributeNS(null,"opacity","0.3");
        }   
    }

function mainloop2() {
    // rotation speed
    A-=Math.PI/120; 
    // refresh time
    k=0;
    for(var i=0;i<6;i++){
        if(TM[i]!=Tm[i]){
            Tm[i]=TM[i];
            // destroy objects
            for(var j in O[k].O)document.getElementById("clock3D2").removeChild(O[k].O[j].o);
            delete O[k];
            // create new digit
            O[k] = new Cdigit2(k, TM[i]);
        }
            // skip colons
        k+=(i==1 || i==3)?2:1;
    }
    // call animation
    for(var i in O){
        for(var j in O[i].O){
            O[i].O[j].anim2();
        }
    }
    setTimeout("mainloop2()",20);
}

function timer2(){
    // HH:MM:SS
    T = new Date();
    h = T.getHours();
    m = T.getMinutes();
    s = T.getSeconds();

    TM = [
        Math.floor(h/10),
        h%10,
        Math.floor(m/10),
        m%10,
        Math.floor(s/10),
        s%10
    ];
    setTimeout("timer2()" ,1000); 
}

function dayDisplay2()
{
    var dayName = 
         new Array("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Thursday",
                    "Friday","Saturday");
      var monthName = 
         new Array("January","February","March","April","May","June","July",
"August","September","October","November","December");

    var today = new Date();

    document.getElementById("date2").firstChild.nodeValue = 
            dayName[today.getDay()-1]+", "
                + monthName[today.getMonth()]+" "
                + today.getDate()+", "+today.getFullYear();
}

]]>

</script>


<rect id="backGround2" x="3" y="50" width="247" height="200" fill="black" stroke="#444" stroke-width="5"/>
<rect id="backGround2" x="3" y="53" width="247" height="194" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="1"/>

<g id="clock3D2">
 <circle id="red2" cx="-150" cy="1000" r="4" fill="red"/>
 <circle id="green2" cx="-150" cy="-150" r="4" fill="green" opacity="0.3"/>
</g>

<text id="date2" x="5" y="240" font-size="20" fill="white">
date
    <animate attributeName="opacity" dur="5s" 
      values="1;0;1" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
</text>

</svg>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple elements on the page with the same id e.g.

```
<rect id="backGround" x="3" y="50" width="247" height="200" fill="black" stroke="#444" stroke-width="5"/>
<rect id="backGround" x="3" y="53" width="247" height="194" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="1"/>
```

(you actually have 4 rects with the same id).

This is invalid and is making everything non-functional. You need to give everything a unique id and adjust the code so that it references the appropriate element id.

You also have the same javascript functions duplicated although since they are exactly the same it doesn't matter at the moment, it will once you give all the elements unique ids though. So you could change the mobile functions e.g. in the mobile case startUp could become mobileStartUp for instance

A more sophisticated solution with less duplication would be to adjust the javascript so that the methods took element id names e.g.

```
function startUp() {

      var myBack = document.getElementById("backGround");
```

might become

```
function startUp(backgroundName) {

      var myBack = document.getElementById(backgroundName);
```

and then you'd adjust the call to be

startUp("background") in one case and maybe startUp("mobileBackground") in the other case so you wouldn't need to have separate functions.

Comment: Please take a look @Robert Longson

Comment: You still have 2 functions called mainloop and 2 functions called startup. There may be more.

Comment: Help!! @Robert Longson

Comment: You need unique variables too i.e. backXOm backYO, backHeight, backWidth, O, TM, Tm and A all need to be changed to something else in one version so they are unique between the two instances.

Comment: Yesss Thank you very much @Robert LongSon. Solved